# .htaccess 2 Dyanamic Rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic url at

```
http://www.technicae.net/cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%|tag|&limit=20
```

where the '|tag|' and '20' part change depending on the tag. This is Movable Type blogging platform which is written in perl. The '|tag|' part is a place holder for the tag. For example, if the tag was 'there' the url would be

```
http://www.technicae.net/cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%there&limit=20
```

and not

```
http://www.technicae.net/cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%|tag|&limit=20
```

I was wondering how to rewrite that in htaccess because everything I try doesn't work. I want it to be

```
http://www.technicae.net/tag/|tag|
```

instead of

```
http://www.technicae.net/cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%|tag|&limit=20
```

can you please help me?

**note**
The URLS are not functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're searching for :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)$               cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/limit/([^/]+)$ cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%$1&limit=$2 [L]
```

This will allow thos kind of url :

- `www.domain.com/tag/<myTag>`
- `www.domain.com/tag/<myTag>/limit/<myLimit>`

But not :

- `www.domain.com/limit/<myLimit>`

Comment: Awesome, but it doesn't redirect from the old link

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

The .htaccess you should use (this may need tweaked) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/([^\.]+)$ cgi-bin/type/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=2%$1&limit=20 [NC,L]
```